# Spring Boot + Webservice (return plain XML at Endpoint)

Tags: web-services

I have an existing application, written by java with Spring boot + webservice.

Recently, I got a requirement from testing department that colleague wants the application to return a response which is typed by him, whatever the response violates XSD.

As [Spring Producing a SOAP web service example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) a reference, how I could control the response?

It's because, normally, the response returned from CountryEndpoint is an object, which is generated according to countries.xsd

Should I implement my own MessageDispatcher/ EndpointAdapter/ Endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have develop my own EndpointInterceptorAdapter.
The reponse returned from Endpoint is clear and then put the XML read from a file, which is provided by my colleague

Here is the code of my EndpointInterceptorAdapter

```
    public class SOIWSSimEndpointInterceptorAdapter extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)  throws IOException {
    InputStream responseFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/java/response/Response.xml"));
    messageContext.clearResponse();
    messageContext.readResponse(responseFileInputStream);

    return true;
}
```

}